# Dynamic dropdown 'WITH' a blank value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have two columns in my excel sheet (Fruit,Country) --

[image]

Here the user can input the fruit type from the dropdown. I have also kept a blank field. i.e. if the user sets the Fruit field 'BLANK', the Country field will be set 'BLANK'.  Now I can create a dynamic dropdown but how to account for the blank ?

My reference sheet I have kept like this, from here I am creating the names to use in the Name Manager.

[image]

But after extensive searching I am unable to solve how to get a blank in the Country if the Fruit is selected blank. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you cheet with underscore or a space?

Comment: Is this for a single set of dropdowns, or are you going to be using these to enter several rows of data? (We can do it either way, just slightly differently).

Comment: there will be several rows of datas involved

Comment: @Asaf -- yes i can, any ideas ?

Comment: How dynamic is the list? Like `A:A` so that unchecking "ignore blanks" would include too many blanks?

Comment: under score "_"  is as good sting as any... put it as the "blank" value of the first list... and under the sub list of "_" put all the values you want to be available

Comment: In cell B1, I assume will be your selection, which will be a number, blanke=1, Apple=2... the nature of your setup. At this point I'm not even sure that you set up the control correctly. Have you right clicked (format control) the control and assigned it the "cell link" to B1? In your image is a blank space, having selected a blank space, where it should be "1", the selection of the blank. From that point you'd have to set up a search, e.g. =VLOOKUP(...). Chime in if you are stuck after reading my concern.